# Чтение данных из созданного файла HDF5

Tags: c++, c

Я использую библиотеку hdf5 на с++, и мне необходимо получить данные из созданного файла с использованием core драйвера. Есть код:

```cpp
    std::vector<int> vec = {7, 1 -2, 0, 8, 6}; // массив для записи в dataset

    H5FD_CORE;

    //создаю виртуальный файл в памяти:
    hid_t faplist_id = H5Pcreate(H5P_FILE_ACCESS);
    H5Pset_fapl_core(faplist_id, 1, false);
    hid_t file_id = H5Fopen("data.h5", H5F_ACC_CREAT | H5F_ACC_RDWR, faplist_id);

    //используя api на с++, создаю группу и датасет с данными
    H5::H5File file(file_id);
    H5::Group group = file.createGroup("/Data");

    hsize_t dims[1];
    dims[0] = vec.size();

    H5::DataSpace dataspace(1, dims);

    H5::DataSet dataset = file.createDataSet("/Data/IntArray", H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT, dataspace);
    dataset.write(vec.data(), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT);

    // тут необходимо вывести в стандартный поток набор байт содержащийся в файле data.h5

    file.close();
```

Comment: ¿Вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: @user7860670, как считать данные из файла

Comment: Если вы используете библиотеку, которая создает файлы определенного формата, записывая туда данные. То должна быть в библиотеке функция считывания этого формата из файла :)

Comment: @FrancNet, мне не нужно считывать формат из файла, мне нужно получить область памяти, в которой создается виртуальный файл для считывания, сжатых данных (просто набора байт)

Comment: "мне необходимо получить данные из созданного файла с использованием..." - я не знаю, может это означает получить что-то в памяти :)